# CSS Positioning Issues: Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, positioning

I'm following this tutorial here http://www.kriesi.at/archives/create-a-multilevel-dropdown-menu-with-css-and-improve-it-via-jquery on adding a menu with jquery.

I've created my menu, but I'm having trouble adding it to wordpress. I opened up the header.php file since I want it to appear below the banner, and I paste it in it's own div, but it always "pushes" everything below it to the right.

How do I stop it from doing this?

Here's the code:

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
<li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">3 Javascript</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">3.1 jQuery</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">3.1.1 Download</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3.1.2 Tutorial</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">3.2 Mootools</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3.3 Prototype</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say without looking at the whole, but based on knowing very little of your problem, the only thing I can recommend you to try is this CSS property:

```
ul#nav {
    position: absolute;
}
```

This way, it will not push other elements away. It might have other consequences tough, depending on other elements you might have.

Comment: Almost, but now the posts are too close too one side. It's weird, because for any "post" page, it works perfect. It's only the front page and the archives that aren't working.

Comment: Just had to change some CSS of the posts. Thanks a bundle!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a closing `</ul>`? You can also use [The W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) to tack down errant tags.